# Error building WCF Service in AppHarbor

Tags: c#, wcf, appharbor

I'm having trouble building a simple WCF Service I wrote. This is the main error message I receive:

> D:\temp\3fsgwk0h.1vu\input\AndroidWCFService.csproj(102,3): error
>   MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The only thing that might make this WCF Service more complicated is that I'm using Entity Framework to connect to the SQL Database that I created on AppHarbor. Is there a config setting I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a blog post that answers your question](http://druss.pp.ua/2013/10/deploy-mvc-4-application-wcf-service-to-the-free-appharbor-cloud/). From the post:

```
You will see that appharbor cannot build the application with WCF service, the following error will be in log:

"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" was not found
To fix this error you should add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets (this file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF folder) to your “testForBlockService” service project. Then open testForBlockService.csproj for edit and replace

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" />
with

<Import Project="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" />
```

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense. I'll try it out tonight! Thanks